# How to create a custom shape - css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to create a custom shape like this image :

[image]

how can I do ?

My CSS :

```
#chevron { 
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 60px; 
  width: 200px; }

#chevron:before { 
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: #337AB7;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);    -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg); }

#chevron:after { 
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #337AB7;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); }
```

My HTML file :

```
<div id="chevron">

</div>
```

But my result isn't what I want :

[image]

Comment: You could alter the `top` of both the pseudos and set `overflow: hidden` on the container or, you could use gradients. Knowing where and how this shape would be used, whether it would have text inside or not etc would help in giving better suggestions.

Comment: There are a tonne of CSS shape generators out there. For example: https://coveloping.com/tools/css-shapes-generator and http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Add the background color to the parent div to fill in the gap
- Place the `border-radius` on the parent div to create the two rounded corners
- Move the `:before` and `:after` down slightly with `top: 20px` so they don't peak out the top of the div

### Example

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/45tyb219/1/) of the below:

```css
#chevron {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #337AB7;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
#chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: #337AB7;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
}
#chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #337AB7;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="chevron"></div>
```

Comment: but when I set an img tag, It will not be good. `<div id="chevron">
  <img  src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/HtYUn.jpg" style="width:120px;height:120px"/>
</div>`

Comment: you should use `skewX()/skewY()` rather than `skew()` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#skew))

Answer (score 2):

You could skip the CSS and use svg:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8odfJ0D4WjEVexHD8q0D?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" width="200px" height="100px">

  <polygon points="0,0 200,0 200,80 100,100 0, 80"
             style="fill:teal;stroke:rgba(0,0,0,1);stroke-width:0" />
</svg>
```

Note that if you need rounded on corners, svg polygons can be tricky as they do not inherently have an attribute similar to `border-radius`.  You can set `stroke-linejoin="round"` and then adjusting the `stroke` width attribute to adjust how much it rounds.  This works good for solid shapes where you can set the stroke color the same as the fill, or if you can have a border of a different color.

HTML:

```
<svg width="300" height="200">

  <polygon points="10,10 210,10 210,90 110,110 10, 90"
             style="fill:teal;stroke:teal;stroke-width:10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

Comment: how can I set border-radius: 4px; for top of shape ?

Comment: slightly more complicated answer.  I can point you in the right direction.  SVG polygon doesn't have a border radius setting, though you can hack it a bit in some situations with stroke settings..I'll add it to the plunker, one sec.

Comment: Using CSS with the svg -- `svg {
border-radius: 10px;
}` -- seems to work fine.

Comment: eh...not quite.  It does apply the style to the border of the svg element, but not what you draw with it..Check my plunker, you can see the effect that produces.  This might be ok in some obscure case, I suppose.

Comment: You can consider using a `path` element instead of `polygon` to make the rounded corners (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30433716/1811992))

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to write on this shape

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>CSS Example</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #chevron{ 
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 12px;
                margin-bottom: 6px;
                height: 40px; 
                width: 200px;
                font-size:40px;
                color:#FFF;
                background:#3794d1;
                border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
            }
            #chevron:before{ 
                content: ''; 
                position: absolute;
                bottom: -10px; 
                left: 0;
                height: 20px;
                width: 50%;
                background: #3794d1;
                -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
                -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
                -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
                -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
                transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
            }
            #chevron:after{ 
                content: ''; 
                position: absolute;
                bottom: -10px; 
                right: 0;
                height: 20px;
                width: 50%;
                background: #3794d1;
                -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
                -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
                -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
                -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
                transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chevron">Welcome</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, if you're going to post a copy from shapes of css, please state your source. However, please kindly note said link is already on the [tag:css-shapes] tag wiki