# how to set a shape to a div

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I would like to set a shape to a `div` tag. Everything works fine, but when I set an `img` tag inside that shape, it does not show well.

My CSS code :

```
#chevron{
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #337AB7;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
#chevron:before { 
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; 
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: #337AB7;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);    -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg); }

#chevron:after { 
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; 
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #337AB7;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); }
```

My html file :

```
<div id="chevron">
  <img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtYUn.jpg" style="width:120px;height:120px"/>
</div>
```

I want to set my shape (`chevron`) as a background and the inner elements should be over it.

http://jsfiddle.net/45tyb219/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `position: relative;` and `z-index: 1;` to your `.img` - alternatively you can also add `z-index: -1;` to the `#chevron:after`.

```css
#chevron{
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #337AB7;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
#chevron:before { 
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; 
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: #337AB7;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);    -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg); }

#chevron:after { 
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; 
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #337AB7;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); transform: skew(0deg, -6deg); }

img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="chevron">
  <img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtYUn.jpg" style="margin-left: 100px;width:120px;height:120px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: plz check it : `<div id="chevron">
  <img  src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/HtYUn.jpg" style="width:120px;height:120px;position: relative;margin-left:100px"/>
</div>`

Comment: Ah I see, add `z-index: 1;` to your image **or** add `z-index: -1;` to `chevron:after`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with CSS but SVG makes it much easier :

```css
svg{width:50%;display:block;margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 50">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="50">
      <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/5NK0H1e.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#img)" d="M5 0 H95 Q100 0 100 5 V45 L50 50 L0 45 V5 Q0 0 5 0z" />
</svg>
```

In this demo, the image is set in the `<pattern>` element and used to fill the shape defined with the `<path />` element.