# Pointed/Angled/Gabled/Pitched Div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need the downward side of a div "pointed". I don't know exactly how to ask/search for this hence the multiple words in the title. I also need it to be responsive.

[image: Pointed Div]

I have made triangles before with CSS, and added triangles to the bottom of divs, but I can't figure out how to make it responsive.

This might be a good place to start, but I can't get very far: http://lawrencenaman.com/css/responsive-slanted-divs-with-css/

Similar to:
[How can I create div with a pointed top with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017502/how-can-i-create-div-with-a-pointed-top-with-css) and [Half hexagon shape with one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873566/half-hexagon-shape-with-one-element)
Except none of these have responsive solutions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what kind of responsive? Like it needs to change color? move?

Comment: @ketan I need a responsive answer. The question you referenced, as well as two others I mentioned in the question, do not have responsive solutions

Comment: @user3049865 Responsive...as in adjusts itself based on viewport (screen) size. I thought that would be a given.

Comment: Might be this  will work for your requirement.


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431910/how-to-create-a-custom-shape-css/30432076#30432076

Comment: @stanze No. That solution is not responsive. Notice the fixed px width of the chevron. Thanks though.